# What is the efficient way to parse JSON array in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

As of now am parsing the JSON data directly from array,without model class. Please suggest the efficient way to parse JSON either to use model class or directly parse JSON data.

Comment: you can use swift's Codable feature to Decode JSON. You can look at [QuickType.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate code for JSON Result

Comment: try https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport this for convert your JSON object to model

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swift 4 then apple has some new **classes** and **protocols** we can use **JSONDecoder** and **Decodable** for decoding from **JSON** data to a model object, and **JSONEncoder** and **Encodable** for encoding from a model object to JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

> The Swift standard library defines a standardized approach to data
>   encoding and decoding. You adopt this approach by implementing the
>   Encodable and Decodable protocols on your custom types. Adopting these
>   protocols lets implementations of the Encoder and Decoder protocols
>   take your data and encode or decode it to and from an external
>   representation such as JSON or property list.

For json decoding you can use Struct and classes which implements [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol. Below is the simple example from developer site

```
struct Landmark: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int
}
```

now you can create the Landmark struct from your JSON data like

```
do {
    let landmark = try JSONDecoder().decode(Landmark.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Apart from Codable protocol there are many third party libraries available like [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) etc. but the recommended way is to try `Codable` protocol first before to thirs party solutions.